# Modify content of file in php

Tags: php

This file stores the number of item ordered to date. Therefore, I will need to read from the file for current number ordered and add it to the current quantity ordered and write it back.

I am new to PHP, so I am not sure what is the best approach here.

The format of the file is as follows:

```
        $filename = "ordersToDate.txt";
        if (!file_exists($filename))
        {
            $file = fopen($filename, "w");
            $toWrite = "Total quantity ordered to date
            \r\nTotal number of apples: ".$appleQty.
            "\r\nTotal number of oranges: ".$orangeQty.
            "\r\nTotal number of bananas: ".$bananaQty;
            fwrite($file, $toWrite);
            fclose($file);
        }
        else
        {
          // read individual item QTY ordered to date, add it with current ordered QTY and write back

        }
```

If the file already exists, I need to read the QTY from it and update it. Is there a quick and easy way to get it (i.e., current QTY to date), provided that I know the string before it?

Comment: Looks like all you're missing is the read part. But why not store the data in a database? File I/O like this can be costly. What happens if two read/writes occur at the same time?

Comment: I don't quite get it what your goal is?! You just want to read the file data and also write to the file if you want?

Comment: And if you really wanted a file, you could write to an excel. There is a really good PHP excel library called PHPExcel

Comment: If the file already exists, I need to read the QTY from it and update it. Is there a quick and easy way to get it, provided I know the string before it?

Comment: @MaTaKazer 1. How can they be ordered by date if you don't save the date in the file? 2. With "update" you mean just add another entry to the end of the file OR reorder the array by date and add the entry then?

Comment: @Rizier123 No, it's not sorting the order according to dates. The file stores the quantity of items(apples, oranges, bananas) **ordered to date**. And I will need to update this file whenever an order goes through.

Answer (score 0):

When you open a file like that you can specify "or die" like this:

```
$filename = fopen("ordersToDate.txt", "w") or die ("Can't open file.");
```

Then you can write to the file like you're doing and then close it.  If the file exists already it will just open the existing one.  If it doesn't exist PHP will create the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// can add another one for 'bananas: ' etc.
$re = "/(?!apples: )(\\d)/"; // for apples

// $str = file_get_contents($filename);
$str = "Total quantity ordered to date\r\nTotal number of apples: 3\r\nTotal number of oranges: 4\r\nTotal number of bananas: 3";

$subst = "5"; // $subst = $new_number;

// replace the number after 'apples: ' with whatever you want
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str, 1);

echo var_dump($result);
// file contents, with apple number replaced with 5 (from 3) can now be written to file

?>
```